# glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST) gives invalid enum (seems to be depreciated - code works though - but why?)

Tags: c++, opengl

Quick question - title says it all:

In my OpenGL-code (3.3), I'm using the line

```
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
```

I've been using my code for weeks now and never checked for errors (via glGetError()) because it works perfectly. Now that I did (because something else isn't working), this line gives me an invalid enum error. Google revealed that glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST) seems to be depreciated since OpenGL 3 (core profile?) or so and I guess, that is the reason for the error.

But that part of the code still does exactly what I want. Some more code:

```
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
// buffer-stuff
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 9, NumParticles);
```

So, did I put something redundant in there? I'm drawing particles (instanced) on screen using 2 triangles each (to give a quad) and in the alpha-chanel of the particle-color, I'm basically setting a circle (so 1.0f if in the circle, otherwise 0.0f). Depth-testing of course for not drawing particles from the back infront of particles further in front and glBlendFunc() (and as I understood glEnabled(GL_ALPHA_TEST)) for removing the bits not in the circle. I'm still learning OpenGL and am trying to understand, why that code actually works (for once) and why I apparently don't need glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)...

Comment: Do you have different depth values for your circles? Do you use `discard` in your fragment shader in case of being outside of the circle?

Comment: Yes, I'm using discard in the fragment shader. Otherwise, I just used to code above, so I guess, only one depth value (standard?).

Comment: `I just used to code above, so I guess, only one depth value (standard?)` the depth value is given by the `z` value that you are writing in your shader(s). But the relevant part is the `discard`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes, I'm using discard in the fragment shader. Otherwise, I just used to code above, so I guess, only one depth value (standard?).

`discard` is the replacement for `glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);`.

> So, did I put something redundant in there?

Yes `discard` and `glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);` would be redundant if you use a profile for which `glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);` still exists and if you use `discard` for every fragment with an alpha for which the `glAlphaFunc` would discard that fragment.

Since you are in a profile for which the `glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);` does not exist anymore, the `glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);` has no effect in your code and can be removed.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer. I just removed glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE),
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) and
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST) and the code still does the same thing. So discard does it all. I was happy back then when the code worked, so I didn't research any further. But I'm also always happier to remove redundant code (altough I guess that should not slow down the code significantly)...

Comment: @PaulAner `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` and `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` is only relevant if you emit fragments with an alpha value that is not `1.0` or `0.0`. If you want some antialiasing for your circles. But blending and depth test is a complex topic.

Comment: `GL_CULL_FACE` is important if you want the front or back of a vertex not to be rendered.

Comment: I put GL_CULL_FACE in because of a tutorial. But viewing the particles from "behind" didn't make a difference either (but since I'm only rotating the position, the circle/quad is always showing it's front anyway). As for antialiasing, I might look into that at some point. Right now, since the fragment shader is interpolating the circle (and thus the alpha-values), discarding everything >0.0 doesn't look very good. But something like discarding everything >0.1 looks OK enough.

Answer (score 2):

Alpha test is a (since ages deprecated) method to only draw fragments when they match some alpha function. Nowadays this can easily be done inside a shader by just discarding the fragments. Alpha testing in itself is also very limited, because it can only decide to draw a fragment or not.

In general, enabling `GL_ALPHA_TEST` without setting a proper [`glAlphaFunc`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glAlphaFunc.xml) will do nothing since the default comparison function is `GL_ALWAYS` which means that all fragments will pass the test.

Your code doesn't seem to rely on alpha testing, but on blending (I assume that since you are setting the `glBlendFunc`). Somewhere in your code there's probably also a `glEnable(GL_BLEND)`.

Comment: Yes, I guessed that blending does it. Weirdly there is no glEnable(GL_BLEND) anywhere. But I'm using discard in the fragment shader. That might do all the "(sort-of) blending" in that case, right?

Comment: Discard in the shader does exactly the same as a alpha test, so you can just remove the blending code and the alpha test enabling and everything should work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just did exactly that. I'm always happy to remove redundant code (altough in this case, I don't think it would cause any significant slowdown).